# How to parse this url in Javascript Language?

Tags: javascript

```
i have url http://localhost/testo.php?id1=20&qty1=5&id2=13&qty2=4&id3=23&qty3=5.5 and so on with id4 etc etc
```

and success get the parameter with code like below:

```
var a = location.href; 
var b = a.substring(a.indexOf("?")+1);
```

the result value of var b is :

```
id1=20&qty1=5&id2=13&qty2=4&id3=23&qty3=5.5
```

i want to parse this result value of var b and also the index which is 1,2 and 3 into javascript integer/decimal variable so the result can be like below:

```
id1  = 20
qty1 = 5
id2  = 13
qty2 = 4
id3  = 23
qty3 = 5.5
```

and the most important thing is how to get the index which is 1,2 and 3

Please help... >.<

Very Thanks :)

Comment: Multiple ?, don't you mean &?

Answer (score 0):

Your url is kinda non standard: http://localhost/testo.php?id1=20?qty1=5?id2=13?qty2=4?id3=23?qty3=5.5

- '?' means you have parameters behind
- '&' should be the parameters separator

Thus your url should be http://localhost/testo.php?id1=20&qty1=5&id2=13&qty2=4&id3=23&qty3=5.5

To parse your GET parameters:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use `getParameterByName()`. The way you're setting it up looks fine:

`getParameterByName('id1');`    # 20
`getParameterByName('qty1');`   # 5
`getParameterByName('id2');`    # 13
`getParameterByName('qty2');`   # 4
`getParameterByName('id3');`    # 23
`getParameterByName('qty3');`   # 5.5

Comment: how to print that getParameterByName('id1'); ? i use document.write but blank

Comment: and how to get the index 1,2,3 ?

Comment: You still have to set each param to a var and then you can call it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://localhost/testo.php?id1=20?qty1=5?id2=13?qty2=4?id3=23?qty3=5.5';

var result = [];
url.split('?').forEach(function(str, index) {
  if(index === 0) {
    return;
  }

  var arr = str.split('=');
  var nameParts;
  if(arr.length > 1) {
    nameParts = /^([^\d]+)(\d+)$/.exec(arr[0]);
    if(nameParts && nameParts.length > 2) {
      result.push({
        key: nameParts[1],
        index: nameParts[2],
        value: arr[1]
      });
    }
  }
});

console.dir(result);

/* 
    output:
    0   Object { key="id", index="1", value="20"}
    1   Object { key="qty", index="1", value="5"}
    2   Object { key="id", index="2", value="13"}
    3   Object { key="qty", index="2", value="4"}
    4   Object { key="id", index="3", value="23"}
    5   Object { key="qty", index="3", value="5.5"}
 */
```

Comment: nice! thx! but how to print the index also which is 1, 2 and 3?